# Variable has a null value but if statement still gets called

Tags: c#

I have an if statement

```
if (materialtype != "WINDOWVINYLREPL"
    || materialtype != "ROOFING"
    && materialtype != "null"
    && materialtype != null)
{                
    subtype = (from a in UEF.MaterialSubTypes 
               where a.MaterialSubType1.Equals(subtype) && a.Code.Contains(materialtype) 
               select a.Code).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

and even though materialtype is equal to null the if statement still gets called and it shouldn't be

Comment: Your first `||` is short-circuiting the rest of the conditions. If `materialtype != "WINDOWVINYLREPL`, then that's a true statement, and that's as much as an `||` needs to know to enter the code block.

Comment: Well, if `materialtype` is `null` then `materialtype != "WINDOWVINYLREPL"` is `true`, so it's logical that the body of the `if` is executed. Why would you expect anything different? If you want it to be not executed in case of `null`, then fix the expression. Use parentheses to group conditions properly.

Comment: `TRUE OR FALSE = TRUE`. It's not a matter of short-circuiting. That's the correct behaviour. The first comparison is TRUE

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos From MSDN: `The conditional-OR operator (||) performs a logical-OR of its bool operands. If the first operand evaluates to true, the second operand isn't evaluated.` The first operand evaluated to true, so everything afterwards isn't even considered. That's short-circuiting.

Comment: @Abion47, yes, but even without short-circuiting the result is the same. Short-circuiting doesn't alter the result of the expression. If one of the operands of an `OR` expression is true, the expression is true whether the other operand is evaluated or not

Comment: Which would be the best way to deal with multiple conditions in an IF statement, should I continue on with the suggestions made or do nested IF statements?

Answer (score 9):

```
if (materialtype != "WINDOWVINYLREPL" || ...
```

the variable is null so certainly it's not equal to "WINDOWVINYLREPL", hence this condition is true and it goes in.

Answer (score 0):

You have an `OR ||` condition. It should be like :

```
if (materialtype != "WINDOWVINYLREPL" && materialtype != "ROOFING" && materialtype != "null" && materialtype != null)
    {                
        subtype = (from a in UEF.MaterialSubTypes where a.MaterialSubType1.Equals(subtype) && a.Code.Contains(materialtype) select a.Code).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Condition was not written with proper brackets. AND, OR conflicted

```
if ((materialtype != "WINDOWVINYLREPL") || (materialtype != "ROOFING" && materialtype != "null")) && materialtype != null)
    {                
        subtype = (from a in UEF.MaterialSubTypes where a.MaterialSubType1.Equals(subtype) && a.Code.Contains(materialtype) select a.Code).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is equivalent to:

```
if((materialtype != "WINDOWVINYLREPL") || (materialtype != "ROOFING" && materialtype != "null" && materialtype != null))
```

Which is true if materialtype == null, because `(materialtype != "WINDOWVINYLREPL")` is true.

The && operator has higher priority than ||

Comment: I think this will do the same thing and enter the if block.  Even if the right side of the `||` operator is False, the left side might be true (assuming there are more than two values for `materialtype`).

Comment: @ChrisDunaway This is what I am saying, I am explaining the problem, not correcting it. It is up to the programmer to correct the condition after he understands the problem according to the logic he wants to test.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use parentheses to separate logic "**OR**" and "**And**"
Because if the value is null the test is always true

```
if ((materialtype != "WINDOWVINYLREPL" || materialtype != "ROOFING")
        && materialtype != null)
    {   
      .....
    }
```